# Pycharm + Django 1.3 + STATIC_URL in templates = Unresolved static reference

Tags: django, pycharm

PyCharm (1.3 and 2 beta) in my Django 1.3 project throws a lot of "unresolved static reference" errors when inspecting my templates for script and style includes.

[In an outdated PyCharm doc](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/working-with-django-templates.html), I found that a small guide that doesn't work in my situation, because my static files are spread over multiple apps. Adding my static dirs to STATICFILES_DIRS also didn't work.

```
Dir structure (simplified):
  app1/static/js/file.js
  app1/static/css/file.css
  app2/static/js/otherfile.js
  app2/static/css/otherfile.css
  templates/template.html
```

­

```
Template.html:
  <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/file.js"></script>
```

file.js resolves when I visit the template on localhost, but not in PyCharm.

**How do I make static files resolve in PyCharm?**

Comment: Kinda late, but that should work out of the box.. You dont need to add your app's static to STATICFILES_DIRS and that should work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PyCharm 2.5 finds my static files again.

The trick is to mark app1/static and app2/static as "Source Root".

`STATICFILES_DIRS` is not working for me.

Comment: That did the trick for me too, with 2.7 EAP. IMHO, this should work out of the box via parsing the `settings.py` file.

Answer (score 10):

Go to Settings in Pycharm 2.73

`Settings >> Project Setting >> Django`

Enable the Django support and provide the paths for the three following files:

```
Project Root
Settings file
Manage.py file
```

When you have given these informations, close PyCharm and restart it.

Answer (score 1):

The selected answer doesn't work for me. What solved it is using a prefix in STATICFILES_DIRS:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # ...
    ("resources", "C:/data/django/myproject/myapp/static"), )
```

as documented in the django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/staticfiles/

Then in your html template:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{%static 'resources/favicon.png' %}" type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 0):

`STATICFILES_DIRS` works for

```
{% static "js/lib/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" %}
```

tag in template. 
Not for `{{ STATIC_URL }}js/lib/jquery-1.8.2.min.js`

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-5568